# Allocating return pointer in child function with malloc() but not getting return data

Tags: c

Can someone please help me understand why my printf statement in the main loop prints nothing? If I add a regular hello world printf statement in the main loop it also does not print anything to the console. However, if I comment out the line that prints the returned data, this hello world print statement does work.

I have tried multiple methods of passing the string data between the two functions with no luck.

```
char * getADCValue()
{
    uint8_t id;
    int32_t adc;
    int32_t volt;
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t ch_num;
    int32_t iTemp;
    uint8_t buf[3];

    bcm2835_spi_begin();
    bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_LSBFIRST );   
    bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE1);
    bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_1024);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(SPICS, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);   
    bcm2835_gpio_write(SPICS, HIGH);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(DRDY, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);
    bcm2835_gpio_set_pud(DRDY, BCM2835_GPIO_PUD_UP);

    id = ADS1256_ReadChipID();
    /*if (id != 3)
    {
        printf("Error, ASD1256 Chip ID = 0x%d", (int)id);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ok, ASD1256 Chip ID = 0x%d", (int)id);
    }*/

    ADS1256_CfgADC(ADS1256_GAIN_1, ADS1256_15SPS);
    ADS1256_StartScan(0);

    while((ADS1256_Scan() == 0));
    adc = ADS1256_GetAdc(0);
    volt = (adc * 100) / 167;

    buf[0] = ((uint32_t)adc >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buf[1] = ((uint32_t)adc >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buf[2] = ((uint32_t)adc >> 0) & 0xFF;

    iTemp = volt;   /* uV */

    char * return_data = malloc(1024);

    if (!return_data)
     return NULL;

    sprintf(return_data, "%ld.%01ld V", iTemp /1000000, (iTemp%1000000)/100000);

    return return_data;

}

int  main()
{
    char * returnValue  = getADCValue();
    printf("Voltage Value: %s", returnValue);
    free(returnValue);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure of the `\r` chars? they have a tendency to move cursor at the start of the line, may overwrite some text.

Comment: Good thought. I tried removing them from the sprintf formatting but no luck.

Comment: Presumably you're aware that you're leaking the memory returned by the function since you don't capture the pointer and pass it to `free()`.  However, that's not the immediate issue.  Did you check that the memory allocation succeeded?  Could that be a factor in your problem, somehow? Note too that the sequence is normally `\r\n` and not `\n\r`.  Again, it isn't clear that this could be the trouble.

Comment: Yes, hadn't got there yet. I have edited to include memory clearing and check for memory allocation. Removed new lines and returns as well. Still no luck as of yet.

Comment: You use `%ld` as the format specifier. Are you sure `int32_t  iTemp;` is a `long`?

Comment: You mention a "main loop" and a "hello world print statement". None of them is in the code you posted...

Comment: And are you sure your program doesn't get stuck in one of the `bcm2835_*` functions or in one of the `ADS1256_*` functions or in the  `while((ADS1256_Scan() == 0))` loop ? Put some more `printf`s at strategic points.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. It ended up being the bcm library calls as suggested. Somehow lost my bcm2835 init call and this resulted in something going haywire with my file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. It ended up being the bcm library calls as suggested. Somehow lost my bcm2835 init call and this resulted in something going haywire with my file descriptors.